# R: Error in eval(predvars, data, env) : not that many frames on the stack

Tags: dataframe, error-handling, frame

I want to make a wilxocon rank sum test in R and got the error:

`wilcox.test(life$p~life$t, mu=0, alt="two.sided", conf.int=T, conf.level=0,95, paired=F, exact=T, correct=T)`

What got wrong?

> Error in eval(predvars, data, env) : not that many frames on the stack